# Parallel transaction from different processes in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, concurrency, transactions, locking

I have two transactions operating on the same table running from different processes:

```
Transaction 1        Transaction 2    |
                                      | T
set x = 1;           set y = 1;       | I
                                      | M
if (y=1) z=1;        if (x=1) z=1;    | E
                                      | 
commit;                               |
                     commit;          v
```

I need the second transaction to be able to see the changes operated by the first transaction (or viceversa). Is there a way to do this (E.g. A lock between processes so that each process occurs after the other has already been commited)?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction 2 will only see the results of transaction 1 if it started after transaction 2 commits. This is known as read consistency. Oracle does not permit "dirty" reads.